# Will a massive particle be attracted to an infinitely long beam of light?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, visible-light

I was attended to [Bonnor beams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonnor_beam). A Bonnor beam is the general relativistic exact solution for the spacetime surrounding an infinitely long straight beam of light (it includes also the spacetime including the interior of the beam, but I'm mainly interested in the outside spacetime). It is said that two parallel beams, traveling in the same direction, will never converge. They will always stay parallel. Two anti-parallel traveling beams will converge though.
Does this mean that massive particles (with initial velocity zero wrt the beam) will only be dragged along the beam? That is will they acquire only a velocity parallel to the beam and no velocity perpendicular to the beam?
Do Bonnor beams, by the way, show that photons can exchange gravitons? If two opposite traveling beams converge they must.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the original paper by Bonnor](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01645484), he finds that geodesics of particles are affected by the beams, not just through gravitational attraction but a Coriolis-like force along them:

[image]

Note that this is velocity-dependent: a particle at rest would not start drifting along the beam. However, it is hard to avoid this since the beam is heavy (after all, it is an infinite mass distribution, it is a wonder it doesn't implode already) and will tend to attract a particle starting from rest: there will be radial velocity too.

The metric does not tell you anything about gravitons, since they are not part of the entirely classical theory of general relativity. But light certainly can bend spacetime.

Comment: But how can the beam collapse if it consists of light (massless)? If one beam of light doesn't converge to the other (when their directions are the same), doesn't that mean that spacetime around one beam is curved in such a way that a massive particle won't accelerate towards the beam? Like a parallel beam of light, traveling in the same direction, won't be attracted, only if it travels in the opposite direction, for which frame-dragging is responsible. Isn't frame-dragging the only effect?

Comment: The beam does not collapse -- it is composed of massless particles (moving on null geodesics) , and if these are moving in the same direction as the beam they are not attracted towards it. However, massive particles move on timelike geodesics and hence *are* attracted to the beam.